# Should I prefer a dry tone or is it OK to create correct but entertaining questions?

Tags: discussion

I've asked [a mousy question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32242258/what-is-the-command-for-promoting-a-peek-preview-to-document/32265725#32265725) and it's been correctly answered. No issues there. However, I keep wondering of it's fully accepted to make the question entertaining **as long it doesn't affect the quality**.

What does the community say?

Comment: It didn't really entertain me...

Comment: @IKavanagh I can change the title to "*..but attemptively entertaining...*". I found the mouse to be very clearly *mousing* on the button. But I might be easier to amuse.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20691482/catch-22-prevents-streamed-tcp-wcf-service-securable-by-wif-ruining-my-christma

Answer (score 3):

I quite like some entertaining questions.

[Example: Flash CS4 refuses to let go](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2193953/73226)

However it is a distraction from the issue at hand so I think it has to be done particularly well to make the trade off worthwhile.

Comment: That question is a work of literature. I don't even work in flash but I both understood what the question meant, and enjoyed every word of it.  It also has over 2000 upvotes, which tells me the community approves of this sort of thing.